# MongoDB: Handle errors from Bulk.insert() method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert, handle, handleerror

I'm using that method, but I do not know how to handle the result. I've checked that [Bulk.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) returns a promise, but I do not have much experience with that topic. This is my code:

```
bulk.insert({
        id_cliente: val1,
        iddoi: val2,
        id_personeria: val3,
        cliente: val4
});

bulk.execute()
```

I have no problems with data insertion, but I want to get the answer, because there are duplicate records and I need to know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the BulkWriteResult object returned from the execute() call.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#BulkWriteResult

if you need more details, you can call getOperations()

Comment: But how should I use it, I found that object and tried to use it before, but I have no response. I'm using: var resul = bulk.execute(); console.log( result.BulkWriteResult );